# Can't get email user claims from Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-identity, microservices, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

I use Identity Server 4 and Swagger in my microservice to authorize. So, I have this configuration on IS side:

```
   public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>()
        {
            new ApiScope("PetAPI", "Pets WebAPI"),
            new ApiScope("NotificationsAPI", "Notifications WebAPI"),
            new ApiScope("ScheduleAPI","Schedule WebAPI")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>()
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new List<ApiResource>()
        {
            new ApiResource("PetAPI"),
            new ApiResource("NotificationsAPI"),
            new ApiResource("ScheduleAPI")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>()
        {
            new Client()
            {
               ClientId = "pmcs-client-id",
               ClientSecrets = { new Secret("client_secret".ToSha256()) },
               ClientName = "M2M Client",
               AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
               AllowedScopes = {
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                   IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                   "PetAPI",
                   "NotificationsAPI",
                   "ScheduleAPI"
               }
            },
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "swagger-client-id",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("client_secret".ToSha256()) },
                ClientName = "Swagger Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "PetAPI",
                    "NotificationsAPI",
                    "ScheduleAPI"
                }
            }
        };
```

And configuration on microservice side:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = AuthConfiguration.Authority;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = AuthConfiguration.RequireHttpsMetadata;
                options.Audience = AuthConfiguration.Audience;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = AuthConfiguration.ValidateAudience,
                };
            })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
            {
                config.Authority = AuthConfiguration.Authority;
                config.ClientId = AuthConfiguration.SwaggerClientId;
                config.ClientSecret = AuthConfiguration.ClientSecret;
                config.SaveTokens = true;
                config.ResponseType = "id_token";
                config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = AuthConfiguration.ValidateAudience
                };

                config.Scope.Add(AuthConfiguration.ScheduleScope);
                config.Scope.Add("email");
                config.Scope.Add("openid");
                config.Scope.Add("profile");

                config.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                config.ClaimActions.MapAll();
            });
```

The method I use to get claims:

```
var emailFromClaims = _context.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
```

It seems that I have this claim in my Id token, but they aren't mapped into user claims.
I really can't understand what's wrong and I'll be exremely grateful if anyone could help me to find a solution.

Link to pull request where I came across this problem: https://github.com/nantonov/PMCS/pull/58

Comment: try `_context.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst("email")?.Value;`

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos The problem is that this claim doesn't come at all

Comment: Where do you check if the claim is there or not? Remember id claims are not going to end up in the JWT access token automatically

Comment: @AviadP., I checked out user's ClaimsPrincipal in debug. Also, as you can see, I explicitly specified the remaining claims I wanted to end up in the user object via `config.ClaimActions.MapAll();`

Comment: My question is, where do you check your ClaimsPrincipal, in the web app or in the API? It appears you have both cookies, and openid connect and jwt bearer schemes enabled. That means you support both access to pages and also an api. These two avenues will have different ClaimsPrincipal objects. The web app one will be based on the cookie and the API one will be based on the JWT.

Comment: @AviadP. I use jwt bearer scheme and open id connect enabled. And I check ClaimsPrincipal in the API

Comment: Check the `IdentityResourceClaim` table in the database. There should be records with (what claims should be returned) per requested scope. Remember: IdentityResource = IdentityScope

Comment: @Pieterjan, I've checked. Everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

By default only a few claims are mapped into the ClaimsPrincipal user object.

You need to manually map the remaining claims that you want to end up in the user object, using:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
   ...
   options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("preferred_username", "preferred_username");
   options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
});
```

see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0  for more details.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you can see from the code in my question, I manually mapped claims using  `config.ClaimActions.MapAll();` I also tried to map only the email claims but it also didn't help

Comment: The claims that are in the ID-token and userinfo endpoint is the one that can be added to the user object,not the access token. is the claims available in either place?

Comment: Now it seems that i have a problem with userinfo endpoint because I get "Forbidden" error when I try to make get request from my api

Comment: Do you make a proper request using the access token? Usuaully the API does not need to ask the userinfo endpoint, its much better to include the necessary claims inside the access otken.

Comment: I finally got email claims via request, but, yeah, it would be better to get it from ClaimsPrincipal object

Comment: I don't really know why I can't get these claims by this way: 

`config.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

 config.ClaimActions.MapAll();`


But can make a get request to userinfo endpoint and everything works.

It can occur because of Swagger client, I suppose...

Comment: Did you try? MapUniqueJsonKey ?

Comment: Yes, of course, I tried

Comment: can you post a sample id-token?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access identity resource claims from the JWT token, they are not automatically included.

Only claims associated with API resources are included in the JWT token. If you want to include the email claim as well, you have to add it as a user claim to the API resource. Modify your API resource definitions as such:

```cs
new List<ApiResource>()
{
    new ApiResource("PetAPI") {
        UserClaims = { "email" }
    },
    new ApiResource("NotificationsAPI") {
        UserClaims = { "email" }
    },
    new ApiResource("ScheduleAPI") {
        UserClaims = { "email" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it didn't help :(

Comment: Are you sure you are actually requesting one of the scopes of these APIs when requesting the access token?